# JMeter Script Recording - Same request, multiple times in same transaction

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I used blazemeter recorder for JMeter script. So recorded the script in blazemeter recorder and then opened jmx in JMeter. There I see exactly same HTTP samplers, multiple times for a same transactions. Any idea why? Please refer the snapshot.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxcgU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Even despite you tried to hide the URLs I don't think they're "the same", at least first part of the domain has differences in these numbers (`21` is not "the same" as `04`)

[BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) doesn't do any magic, it just catches the network traffic between your browser and the system under test and stores it in form of [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

Most probably these are [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests and different endpoints might mean that the application runs on several servers in clustered mode for [high availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability), however it's better to reach out to your application developers for the clarification, not to the random people in the Internet.

Comment: No Dmitri. They are from same domain, you read wrong, you took top part of 21 as 04. All 4 REQESTS IN SNAPSHOTS ARE EXACTLY SAME. and the extra requests return 304 response code. ..so i think i can remove them.